# JavaScript keep track of global variable?

Tags: javascript, regex, global-variables

Im trying to use the questionID  variable  to keep track of some questions and answers.
But it seems I have problem with that the variable lose its memory, for each time I run my function ?  thats what I think anyway.

When i ask for: color, and then follow up with an answer of: pink, purple or green,  it jumps to the last statement; `else if(questionID == -1)`  which is not my intention.

How can I fix this behaviour ?
I run the script locally.

```
var questionID = -1;

function askQ() {
    var findme = document.getElementById('askBox').value.toLowerCase();
    var dontUnderstand = new Array();
    dontUnderstand[0] = "Excuse me, What did You say ?";
    dontUnderstand[1] = "Sorry, I cant understand You now. ^_^";
    dontUnderstand[2] = "Sorry!, I got to go now... CU !";
    dontUnderstand[3] = "ohh... Can you repeat that one more time ?";
    var randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
    if (findme.match(/(age|old)/)) {
        document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML = "ohh,, I am " +
            obj1.age + " years old, How old are You ?";
    }
    if (!isNaN(findme)) {
        document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML = "ohh.. that's kinda old !";
    }
    if (findme.match(/(color)/)) {
        document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML = "My favourite color " +
            " is Purple, What's yours ?";
        questionID = 6;
    }
    if (findme.match(/(pink|purple|green)/) && questionID == 6) {
        document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML = "well...that's cute !!";
        questionID = -1;
    }
    if (findme.match(/(hi|hello)/)) {
        document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML = "Hi there, nice to meet You !";
    } else if (questionID == -1) {
        document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML = dontUnderstand[randomIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: _When i ask for: color, and then follow up with an answer of: pink, purple or green, it jumps to the last statement; `else if(questionID == -1)` which is not my intention_ -> Then why you're setting `questionID` in the `if`-block before to `-1`

Comment: What error message are you getting in the debug console?

Comment: Your `if(findme.match(/(pink|purple|green)/) && questionID == 6){
` is setting the `questionID` to `-1`, which then (during the same function invocation) matches the `else if(questionID == -1){` condition. You should be able to fix this by making your last `if` statement an `else if` of the previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(findme.match(/(pink|purple|green)/) && questionID == 6){
              document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML = "well...that's cute !!";
      // You're setting it to -1.
      questionID = -1;
  }
```

Also, why not limit your pollution of the global object by making `questionID` a property of the `askQ` function.

`askQ.questionID = 6`

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by addint this to the top and bottom of your function:

```
console.log('starting', questionID);


console.log('ending', questionID);
```

Then use your debug log to see what is going on... or you could add a watch and step through your code using firebug or chrome

Also wondering why you are not using jQuery...

Comment: Because jQuery isn't the answer to everything

Comment: @jeff sure - but there has been a lot more testing (especially cross browser) within that library than we would ever want to repeat - who wants to be dealing with support calls "but it doesn't work in opera!"?